# What does an Ethereum Client do?

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereum-classic, besu

I've developed Smart Contracts using Solidity, and then created a front end for them using Web3js. I used Truffle to to get them to communicate. That's how I tried out a couple of Proof of Concepts. I haven't ever deployed anything on the actual Ethereum network.

1. How do I actually deploy the code I've written on the network ?
2. What does an Ethereum Client do when I would actually deploy the apps that I've created?

Comment: What is _Ethereum Client_ ?

Comment: @Зелёный: It is mostly another way of saying *Ethereum Node*.